# "Embler" et "emblée"

Tags: vocabulaire, usage

Dans un ouvrage très récent il y a la phrase :

> Nous nous attaquons d'emblée à l'une des notions les plus  difficiles de toute la physique : l'énergie.

- Quel est le sens de *emblée* dans ce contexte ?
- Le mot vient-il du verbe embler ?
- Pourquoi l'éditeur de texte ne reconnaît pas ces mots ?
- Livio dit que ces deux mots sont inusités. Est-ce correct ?
- Y a-t-il une explication ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Quelle le sens de emblée dans ce contexte ?

La locution *[d'emblée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/embl%C3%A9e)* signifie *tout de suite*, *immédiatement*, *directement*. Ici, on s'attaque à une notion difficile sans passer par des étapes intermédiaires plus simples.

> 2. Le mot vient-il du verbe embler ?

Oui, et *embler* vient lui-même du latin *involare* : « faire main basse, voler dans, se précipiter ».

> 3. Pourquoi l'éditeur de texte ne reconnaît pas ces mots ?

Un éditeur de texte devrait reconnaître *d'emblée*. Le verbe *embler*, lui, a disparu du vocabulaire depuis longtemps, il était déjà répertorié ainsi dans la [quatrième édition (1762) du dictionnaire de l'Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/embl%C3%A9e) :

> **EMBLER**, v.a.
>
> Ravir avec violence ou par surprise. Vieux mot qui n'est plus en usage, & qui ne s'est conservé que dans cet endroit des Commandemens de Dieu en vieux François, *L'avoir d'autrui tu n'embleras*.

En moyen français, existaient aussi *à/en emble*, *emblé*, *emblement*, *emblerie*, *embleur*, *emblison*...

> 4. Livio dit que les mots sont inusités. Est-ce correct ?

C'est vrai. *Embler* est inusité et *emblée* n'existe plus en tant que mot indépendant.

> 5. Y a-t-il une explication ?

*Emblée* ne peut s'utiliser que dans la locution *d'emblée*.

Comment: *Emblée* seul n'existe pas, mais "D'emblée" est relativement courant. Y compris à l'oral.

Comment: @PierreAntoineGuillaume Oui, c'est vrai. Ma réponse laisse-t-elle entendre autre chose ?

Comment: Je pense que si l'on est peu attentif, le 4e point est un peu trompeur. D'où mon commentaire !